# Passing Data to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and trying to pass data from a view to page and am having two problems:

1. The ID that is in the page url is not being passed to the controller
   (customers/details/1)
2. I cannot get the variable to be written to the page. (i've been told
   to try avoiding the use of viewbag and viewdata).

My controller looks like this:

```
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Details(int? pageIndex)
        {
            var Name = "Nope";
            if(pageIndex == 1)
            {
               Name = "John Smith";
            };
            return View(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

My view look like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<p>@Model.Name</p>
```

Comment: please go through the basics of  ASP.NET MVC

Comment: you are returning string `Name`, so  you can use `@Model` directly

Comment: I've tried to find a way to pass the data on various pages, but all using viewbag and viewdata which Im told I should not do.  I have tried the Model on its own, im getting an error that it cannot find the name of the page "nope".

Comment: It needs to be `return View((object)Name);` and in the view `@model string` and then `<p>@Model</p>`